# Le « petit juif » est-il péjoratif ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie, insultes, religion

Je me posais la question en me prenant le coude dans un coin de table. A ce moment là, je me suis fait la réflexion que je venais de me cogner [le petit juif](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/le_petit_juif).

Une autre réflexion personnelle m'est alors venue. Je me suis demandé si je venais d'énoncer un propos raciste voire antisémite. Je vous pose donc la question.

D'où vient l'expression *Se cogner le petit juif* ? Est-ce péjoratif ? Puis-je l'utiliser en société ou serai-je regardé de travers ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ceux ne connaissant pas l'origine de l'expression, en particulier s'ils sont eux-mêmes juifs, risquent de tiquer, sans forcément mal le prendre. C'est justement là qu'il sera bon d'être bien informé à ce sujet.

Différentes sources trouvées sur le net (par exemple [celle-ci](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/frapper-se-cogner-le-petit-juif.php)) indiquent une origine en rapport avec les marchands juifs de tissus, dont ils mesuraient la longueur en aulnes (distance entre la main et le coude), se cognant alors parfois le coude.

C'est à éviter si on est une personnalité publique, mais tout à fait acceptable à mon avis dans un cercle intime, surtout si vos interlocuteurs connaissent votre position concernant l'antisémitisme.